# Bash Multiple Conditions in If Statement and Functions

Tags: bash, function, if-statement

I'm trying to check if the number of arguments is one and if functions that I wrote in my script previously are true , but it does not work:

```
if [ $# -eq 1 && echo "$1" | lgt && echo "Invalid Length - $1" && echo "$1" | checking_another_function_etc ]; then
echo "some output" && exit 1
```

"lgt" is a function name.

I was trying to use (( [[ [ quotes, multiple if statements but it didn't work either. Maybe I should separate the number of arguments checking and functions with quotes, but I'm not sure how to do it. I'm wondering if it is even possible to pass `echo` command to `if` condition.

The thing is I need one `echo` statement after checking of all functions, but after each function I need its own `echo` statement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`[` is an ordinary command (also spelled `test`); the `[`/`]` pair cannot simply surround a command list. Only the `-eq` expression is evaluated by `[`; the others are separate commands joined by the shell `&&` operator.

```
if [ $# -eq 1 ] &&
   echo "$1" | lgt &&
   echo "Invalid Length - $1" &&
   echo "$1" | checking_another_function_etc; then
    echo "some output" && exit 1
fi
```

---

A possible separation of commands may provide what you expect:

```
if [ $# -ne 1 ]; then
    echo "Wrong number of arguments"
    exit 1
elif ! echo "$1" | lgt; then
    echo "Invalid length: $1"
    exit 1
elif echo "$1" | checking_another_function_etc; then
    echo "some output"
    exit 1
fi
```

It is rarely useful to make an `echo` command the LHS of the `&&` operator, because its exit status is always 0.

Comment: it shows every output after every function but it still doesn't show me the output after condition (after ;then)

Comment: @Josh This answer correctly translated what was in the question into valid shell code.  The question, however, does not provide enough information to determine if this is what you wanted or not.

Comment: What is the exit status (expected and actual) of `checking_another_function_etc`?

Comment: @Josh This answer addresses the problem as revealed in the question. If you're not getting the expected output it's just because there is something wrong with your logic. Please fix that.